# Cloudsim: allocate several cloudlets to a VM

Tags: cloudsim

I'm trying to allocate several cloudlets to a single VM and run them after each other by a specific sequence. but as i add them, i gt the following error:

> Broker: Postponing execution of cloudlet 0: bount VM not available
> Broker: Postponing execution of cloudlet 0: bount VM not available
> Broker: Postponing execution of cloudlet 0: bount VM not available
> ...

i used this command:

```
cloudId.setVmId(0);
cloudId.setVmId(1);    
...
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i found the problem. because of lack of host's resources like MIPS, BW, RAM and ... the VMs couldn't run. i increased the host's Resources and now all VMs are up and running the tasks.

so there was no problem with the code and you can queue several tasks to a single VM.